# abort() is called when I try to terminate a std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms

**Note:** I'm using WinForms & C++17.

---

So I was working on a school project. I have this function:

```
bool exs::ExprSimplifier::simplify()
{
    bool completed = false;

    std::thread thread1(&ExprSimplifier::internalSimplity, this, std::ref(completed));

    while (true)
    {
        if (completed)
        {
            thread1.~thread(); // calls abort()
            return true;
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(27))
        {
            thread1.~thread(); // calls abort()
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what I want is to run the following function:

```
// at the end of this function, I set completed = true
void exs::ExprSimplifier::internalSimplity(bool& completed)
```

..on another thread. I also want to check while the function's doing it's thing and the user pressed `esc` key, the thread terminates. But there's where I'm facing issues. This:

```
thread1.~thread();
```

..is calling `abort()`, crashing the application. Now what I think is that this is due to some scope thing of `std::thread`, but I'm not really sure.

---

### Questions:

1. What's the reason for this?
2. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The code calls the destructor on `thread1` twice.  The second time will be a problem.  What you want is `thread1.join()` instead of `thread1.~thread()`.  Also, `completed` is not thread safe.

Comment: Don't try to terminate threads. Either let them run to completion or signal them (for example using a condition variable) that they should terminate voluntarily. Then `join` the threads before terminating the main application.

Comment: There is no need to manually call the thread destructor.  You return statement does that for you automatically, you just need to `join()` the thread before you return.  Also note that since you do not have synchronization around `completed` you have a data race which means undefined behavior.

Comment: You should signal threads to stop (thread should check a state, I prefer condition_variable + mutex + state), then wait for them to have stopped. Never destroy (kill) them, they could be busy with something critical. Side note : I prefer using std::async, it gives me a build in possibility to transfer information back to the starting thread.

Comment: You can't terminate threads - end of story. In the past, they tried to make it so you could terminate threads, but they realized it's impossible to do it without crashing, so now you can't.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the help. So I declared thread somewhere outside the function. It works perfectly now.

Comment: @SolvedGames "So I declared thread somewhere outside the function. It works perfectly now" - So you found a workaround that *seems* to work, by changing the lifetime of the object. I will bet real money that at some point in the future, your workaround stops working. And then you'll be screwed because you don't actually *know* why it seemed to work in the first place, nor what the *real* solution is.. Bad way to solve problems if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't terminate threads - end of story. In the past, they tried to make it so you could terminate threads, but they realized it's impossible to do it without crashing, so now you can't. (E.g. Windows had a `TerminateThread` function, because it's old. C++ doesn't have it, because C++ threads are new)

The only thing you can do is set a variable that tells the thread to stop, and then wait for it to stop.

`~thread` doesn't terminate threads, anyway. All it does is check that you remembered to call `join` or `detach`, and if you forgot to call one of them, it aborts, as you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

What you typically want to do is something along this general line:

```cpp
class doWhatever {
    std::atomic<bool> stop {false};
    std::thread t;
public:
    void run() { 
        t = std::thread([] { 
            while (!stop) {
                doSomeProcessing();
            }
        });
    }

    void stop() { 
        stop = true;
    }

    ~doWhatever() { 
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }
};
```

Exactly what you're going to do in `doSomeProcessing` obviously varies depending on what you really want your thread to do. Some threads have a queue of incoming tasks, and check the variable before processing each incoming task. Others have one long task to do, but if they do there's typically some loop there that you can check the variable at each iteration.

At least in my opinion, for a lot of situations, the ideal is that you check whether you've been asked to shut down something like once very 100 ms. This gives a nice balance--to a person, shutting down with 100 ms of telling it to looks nearly instantaneous, but you're still checking it infrequently enough that it doesn't affect execution speed enough to notice.

If you have a new enough compiler to support it, you may prefer to use `std::jthread` instead of `std::thread`. It basically includes an equivalent of the `std::atomic<bool>` in the thread object.